# plot points and hyperplane in 3d with R

Tags: r, 3d, plot

i already read various posts regarding my topic but could not manage to find a solution.

I want to plot the points

[image]

The Points A and C should be plotted with red color, and Point B with blue.

Furthermore i want to plot the hyperplane H:

[image]

As far i have the following code wich (of course) does not produce the right output:

```
rm(list=ls(all=TRUE))
require("plot3D")
require("rgl")
require("misc3d")


x3<-c(1,0,1)
y3<-c(- sqrt(2),0,sqrt(2))
z3<-c(1,1,1)

color<-c("red","blue","red")

plot3d(x3,y3,z3, col="red")
surface3d(x=0.5,y=NULL,z=NULL,normal_x=1,normal_y=0,normal_z=0)A(1/-sqrt(2)/1)
B(0/0/1)
C(1/sqrt(2)/1)
```

If you have any hints and suggestions you are very welcome!

Comment: I tried doing this last summer and I gave up. Did everything in Sage (IPython).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to plot 3 points and a plane at x=0.5. You can do this relatively easily if you are willing to swap the formal definitions of x and z (and correct for that with the labeling).

[image]

```
library("rgl")

x3   <-c(1,0,1)
y3   <-c(- sqrt(2),0,sqrt(2))
z3   <-c(1,1,1)
color<-c("red","blue","red")
plot3d(z3,y3,x3, col=color, size=3, type="s",
       xlim=c(-2,2), ylim=c(-2,2),zlim=c(-2,2),
       xlab="Z",ylab="Y",zlab="X")
grid <- -2:2
surface3d(x=grid,y=grid,
          z=matrix(.5,ncol=length(grid),nrow=length(grid)),
          col="grey", alpha=.2)
lines3d(x=grid,y=0,z=0, col="grey")
lines3d(x=0,y=grid,z=0, col="grey")
lines3d(x=0,y=0,z=grid, col="grey")
```

Comment: works fine!
But i wonder why we habe to change the formal definitions of x and z.

Comment: Good question! `surface3d(...)` plots surfaces of the form `z=f(x,y)`. You cannot specify the plane `x=0.5` that way (because it is multi-valued in z), but you can easily plot `z=0.5`.